# Why the datagrid is not shown?

Tags: wpf

I have a main windows with a button that open another window that has a user control and this user control has a datagrid. The code is this:

Main windows: code of the button:

```
dlgImprimirControlUsuarioView miView = new dlgImprimirControlUsuarioView();
miView.Show();
```

The code in my second window (codebehind):

```
 public partial class dlgImprimirControlUsuarioView : Window
{
    public dlgImprimirControlUsuarioView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        UserControlView miView = new UserControlView();
        this.ccControlUsuario = miView;
    }
}
```

AXML of the second windows:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfObtenerTamañoControles.dlgImprimirControlUsuarioView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfObtenerTamañoControles"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="dlgImprimirControlUsuario" Height="200" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer Name="svControlUsuario" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="200" Width="300" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <ContentControl Name="ccControlUsuario" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The AXML of the user control that is used by the second windows:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfObtenerTamañoControles.UserControlView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfObtenerTamañoControles"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="0,0,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>

        <ScrollViewer Name="svDatagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="32" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
            <DataGrid Name="dgDatagrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="120" Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Contador" Binding="{Binding}" Width="2.5cm"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I can see the vertical scroll bar of the scroll viewer of the second window, but I can't see the content of this scroll viewer. But I am not able to see the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: `this.ccControlUsuario = miView;` - this is not how it works. `ccControlUsuario` is a generated field. Setting its value does not change the visual structure of your window. You have to set the Window's Content, e.g. `Content = new UserControlView();`

Comment: Or better `ccControlUsuario.Content = new UserControlView();`